# Searching and filtering Android Market app reviews

Tags: google-play-store, app-ratings

There seems to be no way of filtering or searching the app *reviews* in Android Market. This is a problem because it's usually the low-scored reviews that are most useful - they give an idea about what people are finding as disadvantages, so I can decide whether or not those are relevant to me or not.

**Is there some way around this restriction?** Does Google provide the review data in some way that could be searched, for example all reviews on one big page?

Comment: This would be nice, much like Amazon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These days, the Google Play Store (renamed Android Marketplace) *does* in fact have review filtering based on the rating.

Just click on "User Reviews" and the "5 stars", "4 stars" titles for the bar graphic are now clickable, and clicking them displays only reviews with that rating.

Thanks, Google!

Answer (score 0):

The comments are not searchable from the market app, nor are they searchable from the site, but you can search google using `site:market.android.com my search terms here` and it does include the comments when searching.

All the comments are also visible on the market site under the "user comments" tab for the application.

Comment: However, the site-wide google search isn't limited to a particular app. And the comments on the market web site are only displayed 10 at a time, so they're not very searchable.